# ReactJS in an existing HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm creating my first application with ReactJS. So I want to know if React can be used (added) in an existing HTML ?

Please help me

Answer (score 5):

Potentially YES.

You can use React only to create specific dynamic widgets in an existing website. You are not forced to render/manipulate ALL your DOM with React.

When you render a React component you need to specify the root DOM node where it will be rendered.

Just to make an example:

```
class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="Sebastian" />, mountNode);
```

In this case mountnode will be a reference to a specific dom node within your page. React will work only inside that node, so if you don't manipulate it with other libraries/pieces of javascript code everything should work as expected

Comment: Would you be able to comment on, the performance aspect of it? If my only / the major requirement is the manipulation of existing  HTML, is React the best weapon of choice? Or should I consider using something else?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can render a React component within your current DOM. This might be useful for you: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: so we need to transpile anyway if I understand well?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can use React with or without jsx: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html

Comment: I see I can specifically avoid to transpile if I write directly my component in JS if I understand what you mean logically

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just look at your HTML code to see which part's you would like to be dynamic then add in the ReactJS goodies. It all depends on what you need and your understanding of the ReactJS library.

Here is a tutorial that may help.

[ReactJS Tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html)